# How could the machine in Gantz manipulate life and death?

Tags: gantz

In the anime *Gantz*, after you die, you're teleported to a special room where a black ball orders you to do some missions in order to continue your life. You can win special prizes with the danger of possibly dying again and only get revived by the exchange of points. How is this possible? How does this machine have power over life and death, and even the power of resurrection?

Comment: I don't think it's ever explained how Gantz works. It's alien technology that's been mass produced by humans for the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to gantz.wikia.com:

> The black spheres known as Gantz, are objects with seemingly impossible abilities, mass produced in a factory in Germany, using alien military technology. This technology was sent to Earth by a species to help them fight off another alien species that had previously tried to invade them. Each Gantz sphere has a person inside, which the Room of Truth reveals was just a random person duplicated about to provide an interface. The alien broadcast only contained military technology, the point system and other aspects created by humans.
>
> When [the people in the Room of Truth are] asked about souls, they were told the soul is just data, stored somewhere when they died, and would be reincarnated as someone else later on.

It seems the Gantz clones/duplicates a physical body and then uses the "data" of a soul from the original human to put them in the new body.

Comment: Congratz that is a good answer :)